# ASP.NET Core with vite-react: Cors problem when unabling proxy

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, cors, vite

As I created a project with ASP.NET Core and vite-react, I noticed something in my vite-config:

```
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [plugin()],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
        }
    },
    server: {
        proxy: {
            '^/weatherforecast': {
                target: 'https://localhost:7047/',
                secure: false
            }
        },
        port: 5173,
        https: {
            key: fs.readFileSync(keyFilePath),
            cert: fs.readFileSync(certFilePath),
        }
    }
})
```

As the config shows, the proxy server enhanced client to bypass the cors in server. But I want to remove these configs and resolve the cors with different approach like:

My `startup.cs` file:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var MyAllowSpecificOrigins = "_myAllowSpecificOrigins";

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(MyAllowSpecificOrigins, builder =>
    {
        builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
               .AllowAnyMethod()
               .AllowAnyHeader();
    });
});

builder.Services.AddHttpLogging(logging =>
{ });

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseDefaultFiles();
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseHttpLogging();

app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();
app.MapFallbackToFile("/index.html");

app.Run();
```

Issues continue to perpetuating, please help me. I'm new to the field. Does it relate to https start up ? or something ? Thank you.

Comment: Which server is actually giving you the CORS error?  You've provided literally no debugging information .

Comment: *unabling* is not a word - either you want to **enable** the proxy (turn it ON), or you want to **disable** it (turn it OFF) - which is it? Not clear from your question ....